# "return *this" assignment operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this-pointer

```
Fraction& Fraction::operator= (const Fraction &fraction)
{
    // do the copy
    m_numerator = fraction.m_numerator;
    m_denominator = fraction.m_denominator;

    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Fraction fiveThirds(5, 3);
    Fraction f;
    f = fiveThirds; // calls overloaded assignment
    std::cout << f;

    return 0;
}
```

I have some problems with the concept of `return this` when overloading the assignment operator.

In the main function `f = fiveThirds` will call the assignment operator, and it will return `*this`, i.e. return a `Fraction` object!

The problem is `f = fiveThirds` will return the object, but there isn't any Fraction object to receive it!

In the **assignment chain** `x=y=z`, `y=z` will return an object (`k`) which will be assigned to `x`, however `x=k` will also return an object, so who receives this object?

I've done my best to describe my problem.

Comment: Nobody recieves it, why is that problem? If you want to know why there is a `return *this;`, try writing an overloaded `operator=` with a `void` return. Then write the code `a = b = c;` and see what happens.

Comment: Why do you think it is any different than `int foo()` returning an `int`, but when it gets called without the result being assigned to any variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is f = fiveThirds will return the object, but there isn't any Fraction object to receive it!

More accurately, it returns a reference to an object.

> so who receives this object?

The return value is discarded.

There is no problem.